# How do I run pyspark on a single docker container

Tags: docker, pyspark

We are trying to run pyspark in a single docker container. To say we are having some trouble would be an understatement. Here the main part of the code and configuration.

**spark-defaults.conf**

```
   spark.driver.memory 8g
   spark.executor.memory 4g
   spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled true
   spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled true
```

**Relevant Code**

```
def call_nlp(spark, ids, nlpRequests):
   dataframe = get_spark_dataframe(spark, nlpRequests)

   logger.debug('Applying model transform')
   df_predictions = model.transform(dataframe)
   logger.debug('Done model transform')

   logger.debug('to pandas')
   pdf = df_predictions.where(df_predictions.ESID.isin(ids)).toPandas()
   logger.debug('to pandas done')
   results = pdf.to_dict('records')

   return results
```

We are trying to process messages from a queue and then calling this function. We are batching our requests. nlpRequests consist of an array of objects with 5 columns. Even if we only do 2 at a time it takes several minutes and uses a ton of memory. Can you see anything we are doing terribly wrong? Anything config changes that would drastically improve our performance? I appreciate any help you can offer